# Android TextView with scrollbars and maxHeight

Tags: android

I need to set the TextView maximum height (either using maxHeight or maxLines). And if there are more lines of text the scrollbars should be shown. What markup should I use for this?

Initial idea was to wrap TextView with ScrollView, but ScrollView has no maxHeight attribute.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
    >
</TextView>
```

Code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Note:

The android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable" is used to avoid text fade out when textView is touched.

Comment: When I try this, the TextView displays scrollbars but I can't actually make it scroll.

Comment: You have to execute this from code: `TexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())`;

Comment: I used this approach since I could not ellipsize more than two lines. Thanks.

Comment: @alex2k8 4 years later your answer helped me. Wasted an hour figuring this out.