# Alert Dialog Linkify but keep text white

Tags: android, fonts, colors, android-alertdialog, linkify

Hello I am using the following code to linkify email addresses and urls and that is working just as i need it to however if you click any where besides the urls and emails the white text that is unlinked becomes black and unreadable. Not a huge deal but just something that's annoying any help on formatting the color of the unlinked text onclick would be greatly appreciated.

```
            final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Some text here before link http://www.google.com some more text then email fake@fake.com");
        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
        final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMethod.this)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.about)
            .setTitle(R.string.about_title)
            .setMessage( s )
            .create();
        d.show();
        ((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

So now the following text "Some text here before link some more text then email" shows white in the dialog but turns black when pressed

**EDIT:**

*Java*

```
       LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       View view = li.inflate(R.layout.link, null);
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setTitle("Insert Title Here");
       builder.setView(view).create().show();
       TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link1);
```

*XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/link1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Body text with email fake@fake.com and a website http://google.com"
   android:autoLink="web|email"
   android:textColorLink="#0000ff"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the correct way to do this, but if you explicitly set the textColor attribute, you can get around this issue.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

I would be remiss if I didn't remind you to use [styles](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) when setting your text color, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Set this on your TextView in xml

```
android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478615/android-textview-with-scrollbars-and-maxheight/2480558#2480558).