# Custom Text Bar

Tags: android

Hello i am looking for a way to have a text box (like so) with my disclamer in it so i would like a way of haveing a scroll bar up & down because the text will be a bit long and i cant fit it in the box at the moment.

```
   http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6303/introqm.png



   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         style="@style/LYLBKGRD" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

thank you

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: Try wrapping your `EditText` in a `ScrollView`. It is a little difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry people well when i write lots of text in the box the text just gos down but i cant see it thats why i would like to get a scroll bar

Comment: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9018/intro2e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following...

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit_text"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:maxLines="3"
     android:scrollbars="vertical">
</EditText>
```

[Android TextView with scrollbars and maxHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478615/android-textview-with-scrollbars-and-maxheight)