# Multiline TextView without words wrapping on 4.x?

Tags: android

I want to create a TextView that does NOT wrap text, and allow vertical/horizontal scrolling?
The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478615/android-textview-with-scrollbars-and-maxheight/2480558#2480558) no longer works on 4.0.3.

Is there any solution for 4.x?

Comment: The TextView wraps the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your text in a `HorizontalScrollView` for horizontal scrolling:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
        >
    </TextView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

For vertical scrolling use `ScrollView`.

Also, this XML was just grabbed from the answer you referenced.