# How to update the scrolling text in my activity from the web?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

Hi i am new to android and i am developing an app are there any tutorials which teach me on how to add scrolling text to my app.

I also want to update the text using a website ie; consider for example i am displaying the details of some company then i need to get the data from the companies website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Scroll view if you are added the Textview with the wrap content means it will
get scroll automatically. the textview attributes must be supports multiline .

```
<Scrollveiw>
<somelayout>
<textview> </textview>
</somelayout>
</Scrollview>
```

that design should be like that. we have scroll listener.. at the end of scroll listener you can call website and add the website details.

Thanks

Comment: do you know any online tutorials?

Comment: let me search and suggest you..the best

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android   in this you will be get text scroll as per the touch listener..  Sample 2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478615/android-textview-with-scrollbars-and-maxheight