# Title not center vertically on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` title that will center vertically when the message content of the dialog does not need scrolled, as seen below:

[image]

Now when the message content needs to be scrolled the title is no longer vertically centered, as seen below:

[image]

I have tried setting the title and icon initially using the following:

```
builder.setTitle("Help");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.help);
```

And the title does not center in the second situation with the above code. I have since tried to switch to an XML layout for the title and using `builder.setCustomTitle(...);` to set the title, with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/help"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Help"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#ff33b5e5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried the attributes `minHeight`, `gravity`, `layout_gravity`, and `padding`. I have been able to center the title in the second situation using the `padding` attribute but then the title in the first situation is no longer center. While `padding` could work, I would like to find a solution that will keep the title centered in each situation, independent of if the message needs scrolled. I feel there is something simple and/or straightforward that I have overlooked.

Also, the message content is simply set using `builder.setMessage();`.

**EDIT 1:** I should clarify that I do not want the title centered horizontally, only vertically with it left aligned plus a margin/padding. Ultimately I want each title bar to appear like the first image above.

**EDIT 2:** Here is the java code for the dialog, if it helps:

```
public class HelpDialog extends DialogFragment{
// Bundle variables/args
final static String ARG_HELP = "help";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_help_title, null);

    Bundle args = getArguments();

    //initial way it was done
    //builder.setTitle("Help");
    //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.help);

    //now with the custom xml
    builder.setCustomTitle(view);
    builder.setMessage(args.getCharSequence(ARG_HELP));
    builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this with a more custom XML layout that contains the message `TextView` instead of using `.setMessage()`.

The XML ended up being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/help"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Help"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ff33b5e5"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#ff33b5e5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="16"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="7dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Java code ended up as:

```
public class HelpDialog extends DialogFragment{
// Bundle variables/args
final static String ARG_HELP = "help";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_help_title, null);

    Bundle args = getArguments();

    builder.setView(view);

    TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    message.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
    message.setText(args.getCharSequence(ARG_HELP));

    builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

In order to get the scrolling for larger messages to function properly the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478615/android-textview-with-scrollbars-and-maxheight) was used.

This code gave me the following results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView title_txt = new TextView(this);
    title_txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    title_txt.setText("Hello");
    title_txt.setTextSize(16);
    builder.setCustomTitle(title_txt);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
                @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         {
         }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
   {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
    });
   builder.show();
```

Comment: This code work fine for title that appear in center.. Thanks

Comment: The TextView in this Code is created Dynamically So You dont need it in xml file...

Comment: This still pushes the title upwards, not centered, in the second situation described above.

Comment: remove padding and then try

Comment: Is your Dialog message larger then the height of the screen, thus requiring you to scroll the message? That is when I am running into these problems, otherwise the title is perfectly fine.

Comment: And i have edited my code first try it in simple activity

Comment: I did try a simplified version and it still did not work in the second situation described above. Have you had success in the above situation where the message needs scrolled? I have the title centered just fine in simple situations where the message does not need scrolled, it is the situation when it needs scrolled that the problem arises.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81983/discussion-between-mahesh-suthar-and-troniczomb).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the gravity to just 'center'? Get rid of the padding etc.

Comment: This centers the title horizontally, however the vertical is still not centered in the title.

Comment: Try setting the gravity value to center_horizontal|center_vertical

Comment: That is what I have and am having issues with the view still not actually centering.

Comment: Make the root a RelativeLayout. Inside this a LinearLayout whose width and height are wrap_content. The linear layout contains your icon and textview. Add the layout_centerInParent attrribute to the linearlayout and set it to true.

Comment: That still did not work. Thanks for the effort though.